# Does facebook site backlink affect SEO?

Tags: seo, facebook, backlinks

I am running website and one FB website.
I have backlinks from FB site  to my normal site.
Does it affect SEO ?
Does the FB  site backlink count the same as a normal website backlink ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google doesn’t seem to be using Facebook and Twitter social signals when it comes to ranking. However, there are obviously still plenty of benefits and marketers shouldn’t cease those benefits simply because there doesn’t seem to be direct relation between those two social media platforms and Google ranking.

Here's a link for further understanding ->

https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/news/2325343/matt-cutts-facebook-twitter-social-signals-not-part-of-google-search-ranking-algorithms

Comment: This was done after FaceBook "likes" were artificially inflated (surprise surprise) to effect search engine rank. Now "likes" are basically useless and Google does not care one whit. One of the problems with social media was it's general unreliability across the board as signals of importance and/or popularity. The data was just too dirty. You have to ask yourself this, If I can manipulate something, does Google use it? The answer is always, NO! FB links are more of the same. Cheers!!